# how to change ionic images when some condition occur

Tags: ionic-framework

in my ionic project i want to display images with some condition. that is ,i receive a data from API, if it is " Landed" the image want to display with Green color, if "Cancelled" the image want to display with red color.how to possible.

```
    <div class="col" style="padding-top: 10px"><img src="assets/statusicon/arrive_onTime.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

consider the two images are 'arrive_onTime.png' and 'cancelled.png'
change the code in HTML part to:

```
<div class="col" style="padding-top: 10px"><img [src]="img_url"></div>
```

and in ts file, declare img_url variable,

```
this.img_url = "assets/statusicon/arrive_onTime.png" //on Landed condition
this.img_url = "assets/statusicon/cancelled.png" //on the cancelled condition
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work
my code :

`  <ion-card *ngFor= "let item of objectData;let k=index;" >
    <ion-card-content >
    {{item.departureAirportFsCode}}</div>
        <div class="col" style="padding-top: 10px"><img src="assets/statusicon/arrive_onTime.png"></div>
       
      <label style="padding-left: 40px;font-size: 18px">{{item.status | statusupdator}}</label><label style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 5px;">-</label><label>departs in 2 hr 4mins</label>
    </ion-card-content> `

Comment: have you changed html and ts both? because this must work, I used it in many projects. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have two HTML img elements, one for each image, and use an  `ng-show` or an `ng-hide` attribute on each one. e.g. If you have a variable from your API with a Boolean value, lets call it `data.delayed`, then your delayed image would gave the HTML attribute `ng-show="data.delayed"` and the on-time one `ng-hide="data.delayed"` etc.

Comment: This is assuming the images are different. If they're the same image but you want a different background color behind each image then consider using a CSS class for the color, and ng-class.

Comment: These approaches do work so perhaps you might want to share your code so we can help point things out? e.g. Your HTML and your controller.